# sscanf equivalent in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, regular-expression, c

I have a file which has some stats and counters stored for some ACL rules. I want to design a shell script to read that file and parse those counters.

I have done the similar thing in `c programming language` where I have opened and stored the content of the file in some buffer and with `sscanf`, I have parsed the output of the file

Below is the content of files

```
vlan_id: 0
HITS    ACL rules:
0   0: allow icmp src 1.1.1.1 dst 1.1.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0,
0   1: deny icmp dst 6.8.9.1,
0   2: deny icmp src 3.2.2.1,
0   3: deny tcp src port 3210,
0   4: deny tcp src 6.0.9.9,
0   5: deny udp src port 432,
0   6: deny udp src 43.43.43.1,
0   7: deny tcp src port 435,
0   8: deny udp dst port 554,
22  9: deny all,
the number of passed packets: 0
the number of dropped packets: 22
```

In c programming language, I have wrote the below code to parse it

```
   //Read atmost 127 characters or till it encounter comma(,).
   num = sscanf(line, "%d %d: %127[^,\n]",&hits,&n,&rule[0]);
   if (num ==  3)
   {
       g_list_of_rules[i].hits = hits;
       strncpy_s(g_list_of_rules[i].rule,
                 ACL_MAX_STR_LEN, rule,
                 ACL_MAX_STR_LEN-1);
       i++;

   }
```

Similar thing I want to accomplish in the shell script.

I mean this sscanf functionality `( sscanf(line, "%d %d: %127[^,\n]",&hits,&n,&rule[0]); )` where I am parsing and storing three values in three different variables. So similar kind of functionality I am looking in shell script or in any other linux utility like `sed` or `grep`

For example, for the below rule,

`0   0: allow icmp src 1.1.1.1 dst 1.1.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0,`

all three values I want in separate variables.
So if I do `echo $n1, $n2, $str`
then `n1` should print `0`, `n2` should print `0` and `n3` should print `allow icmp src 1.1.1.1 dst 1.1.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0`

if someone has idea or thoughts, please share it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with `awk`

```
awk -F': ' -v OFS="," '{split($1,a," "); split($2,b,","); print a[1],a[2],b[1]}' input_file
```

This will put in variable `a[1]` the first zero, in `a[2]` the second zero and in `b[1]` the rest of the line (w/o comma)

Comment: Thank you for response. I have a question, how to display it in console?. When I execute the above command it does not print anything

Comment: @vivek, will edit my answer and give you example output you can modify depend of your requirements.